# How to migrate a class using Generic enums with the Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How would you migrate this Car Class to a database using the Entity Framework?

I have a Main car class (which inherits from a Car Interface Class) with one Generic property called Part

```
public class Car<Parts> : GenericCarInterface
{
    public Parts Part { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have several enums representing different parts that can be passed into the Generic Parts property of the Car Class

```
public enum VokswagenParts
{
    VWWheels,
    VWLights,
    VWEngine
}

public enum TyotaParts
{
    ToyotaSpoiler,
    ToyotaAirFilter,
    ToyotaBrakes
}

public enum FiatParts
{
    FiatExhaust,
    FiatSuspension,
    FiatCVOuter
}
```

I envisage setting up an ApplicationDbContext as follows but the EF does not know what to make of the Part property

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"ConnectionStringHere");
    }

    public DbSet<GenericCarInterface> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Any Ideas on the ways that this can be accomplished using Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your enums, it looks like each part has a unique name. if you don't mind whether your parts are grouped or not, you could put all your parts together in single enum.

```
public enum Parts {
    VWWheels,
    VWLights,
    VWEngine,
    ToyotaSpoiler,
    ToyotaAirFilter,
    ToyotaBrakes,
    FiatExhaust,
    FiatSuspension,
    FiatCVOuter
}
```

then in your Car class you can do this

```
public Parts Parts { get; set; }
```

EF should be able to handle the rest.

Comment: Thank you FRANCISCO this would be an ideal solution however i do need to differentiate between the enum types later on in my code. 

I think i may have figured out a solution if i can create a separate class in my repository to hold the enum number values and the enum type names, then i can persist that standard class to the database then simply re-compile the code back  to the original Car class format just before transferring it between layers

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have figured out a solution.

If i can create a separate class in my repository to hold the enum number values and the enum type names:

```
public class Car
{
     public Guid CarId { get; set; }
     public Part Part { get; set; }
} 

public class Part
{
    public Guid CarId { get; set; }
    public Guid PartId { get; set; }
    public int Enum { get; set; }
    public string EnumName { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can persist that standard class to the database then simply re-compile the code back to the original Car class format just before transferring between layers

I might create a separate enum for the part names just to keep it strongly typed but I like the idea of having the names persisted not just enum numbers